# Event synchronization between two threads in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, thread-synchronization

I have two threads, lets say thread "A" and thread "B".
Thread "A" post's custom QEvent to thread "B", and then it should wait till thread "B" processes this event.

What I did so far:

My event class:

```
class IPCMessageEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
   IPCMessageEvent(QWaitCondition* pConditions) : QEvent(IPC_MESSAGE_RECEIVED)
                                                , mpWaitCondition(pConditions)
   { };
   ~IPCMessageEvent()
   {
      mpWaitCondition->wakeOne();
   };
private:
   QWaitCondition* mpWaitCondition;
};
```

My thread "A":

```
QWaitCondition recvCondition;
IPCMessageEvent* pEvent = new IPCMessageEvent(&recvCondition);

QCoreApplication::postEvent(gpApp, pEvent);

QMutex  mutex; 
        mutex.lock();

recvCondition.wait(&mutex, IPC_MESSAGE_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
```

My thread "B": Processes the received event and destroyes it. *~IPCMessageEvent* destructor is called and therefore `wakeOne()` will be initiated for the `recvCondition` in thread "A".

Everything seems to work just fine, **it's just one thing**!
It looks like sometimes *~IPCMessageEvent* is called sooner then expected...

```
QCoreApplication::postEvent(gpApp, pEvent);

<---- pEvent is already destroyed here ---->

QMutex mutex; 
       mutex.lock();
```

So my `recvCondition.wait(&mutex, IPC_MESSAGE_WAIT_TIMEOUT);` will be locked and will reach  the timeout.

Are there any other ways of doing this kind of synchronization?
Or maybe someone have any suggestions how to fix/overcome this problem?

Comment: By the way, you should really go back to your previous questions and accept the best answers. Otherwise people will stop bothering with your questions at all and you won't get any answers in the future.

Comment: Thanks Johannes S. for the tip ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a classical **race condition**. Your thread A may is interrupted directly after posting the event and thread B then processes and destroys it. Since notifications of condition variables have only an effect if somebody is already waiting, you miss the notification and thus your block infinitely.

So you need to lock the mutex before posting the event. However, this requires that your thread B **also** needs to lock this mutex when processing the event. Otherwise, you cannot prevent the race condition as thread B has no reason to wait for anything (or to know that it should "wait" until thread A is ready waiting on the condition variable).

**Alternative:**

If you use a signal/slot connection between the two threads (or the objects living in the two threads), you can use a `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`. This ensures that thread A blocks after emitting the signal until the event loop in thread B processed it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Johannes, 
I would really need to try and use your suggested alternative with signals/slots.

What I did for now is:
I've created a QMutex and boolean flag that are used between thread "A" and thread "B".

```
bool    mIsProcessingMessage;
QMutex  mIsProcessingMessageLock;
```

In thread "A" I'm posting my event like this:

```
IPCMessageEvent* pEvent = new IPCMessageEvent();
{   // Inform everyone that we will be processing our message.
    QMutexLocker locker(&mIsProcessingMessageLock);
    mIsProcessingMessage = true;
};

QCoreApplication::postEvent(gpApp, pEvent, Qt::HighEventPriority);

forever  // Loop until event will get processed.
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mIsProcessingMessageLock);

    if (mIsProcessingMessage == false)
       break;

    ::Sleep(2);  // Don't load up the CPU.
};
```

In thread "B" when my event is processed I just set my "mIsProcessingMessage" flag to true like this:

```
{
   QMutexLocker locker(&mIsProcessingMessageLock);
   mIsProcessingMessage = false;
};
```

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it works for now ;)

Comment: you could still go with your condition variabl approach. I suggest you read up a bit on thread synchronization and how condition variables work. Basically, you need to "share" a mutex and a condition variable. Lock the mutex before posting the event and wait on the CV (which releases the mutex). Acquire the mutex in the event processing thread, process the event, release the mutex, and then notify the CV.